GPUImageView (FrameLayout) scale with pinch zoom not working
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

I add this code for pinch zoom in GPUImageView class.
Help me to solve this not able to pinch zoom in GPUImageView image.
